# Comparar una columna de un Array con 1 fila en otra tabla usando Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, bootstrap

Espero poderme explicar de la mejor forma estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Laravel 5.7 y tengo un problema el cual describo a continuación:

Tengo la tabla statusprestamos

```
id | idprestamo | totalprestamo  | status
1       1             500          pendiente pago
2       1             500          pendiente pago
3       1             500          pendiente pago
4       2            1000          Pagado
5       2            1000          pendiente pago
6       2            1000          pendiente pago
```

Obviamente la columna idprestamo va ligada con la tabla prestamos

```
id  | nombre |  
1       Juan
2      Pedro
3      Isabel
4      Luis
```

Lo que requiero es que tengo una página donde me muestra la corrida de la tabla statusprestamos con la cual no tengo problema, el problema es que quiero que me busque en el IDPRESTAMO y lo compare con la columna ID de la tabla prestamos, y me muestre solo ese resultado que seria el nombre de la persona

Cliente: {{$prestamos->nombre}}   <--- Aqui es donde esta mi problema al hacer el comparativo, si lo hago de esta forma, me arroja el error "Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object (View:  porque se trata de

```
No. | Cantidad | Status

1   |  500     | pago pendiente

2   |   500    | pago pendiente

3   |   500    | pago pendiente
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, sin embargo nunca he entendido porque responden con otra pregunta... NO es más sencillo responder intenta de esta forma y se acabo, no todos somos eruditos...